# Robot framework: how can I get current instance of selenium webdriver to write my own keywords?

Tags: java, selenium, robotframework

I have a maven-powered Robot-framework project in java that uses selenium 3.4.0 dependency, robotframework 3.0.2 dependency, markusbernhardt's selenium2library version 1.4.0.8, and robotframework-maven-plugin version 1.4.7.

My robot tests live in the *src/main/test/robotframework/acceptance* folder, while in *src/main/java/mypackage* I created a Customized.java file to set a system property for the browser driver path (I then import this library in my tests:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             Selenium2Library
Library             mypackage.Customized
```

This works perfectly. But now I'd like to implement my own keywords to extend Selenium2Library. But I'm not sure how to obtain the current WebDriver instance that is running.

I mean, if I weren't using Robot and just plain Selenium, I'd do something like this:

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.doSomething();
```

However, in this case I don't want to instantiate a new WebDriver but instead get the one that is currently running (which Robot automatically instantiated). How can I do that?

I've so far created a `Selenium2Library` object and set it with the value returned by `Selenium2Library.getLibraryInstance();` but that's not giving me access to selenium's methods (e.g.: getCurrentUrl() is not listed).

Answer (score 5):

in python it can be done with following code

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


def _browser(self):
    return BuiltIn().get_library_instance('Selenium2Library')._current_browser()
```

Comment: Any idea how this could be done for getting the current instance of application running from Robot's AppiumLibrary? I need to write some custom keywords for Appium's TouchAction; Robot's AppiumLibrary does not expose this API.

Comment: Answer to my own question: For Appium, you can get the current app by calling:

BuiltIn().get_library_instance('AppiumLibrary')._current_application()

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a solution, but I'm not sure it's the right approach:

```
public class Customized {

    private static Selenium2Library s;
    private BrowserManagement b;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public Customized() throws ScriptException {
        try {
            Customized.s = (Selenium2Library) Selenium2Library.getLibraryInstance();
        } catch (javax.script.ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        b = s.getBrowserManagement();
        driver=b.getCurrentWebDriver();
    }
}
```

Now the selenium methods are available from the driver object. However, there might be a better way to do it, as there's this message in the `javax.script.ScriptException` exception: "*Access restriction: The type 'ScriptException' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar')*"

Answer (score 0):

For newer Selenium version (4.0) the following snippet can be used:

```
class SelCustomLib():

def get_browser_driver(self):
    return BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary').driver
```

Answer (score 0):

Here if you want to get instance of the webelement from robot framework and use into python code for selenium method..

${element} =    Get WebElement    ${xapth_of_element}
def get_captcha_text(self,element):
with open('logo.jpg', 'wb') as file:
file.write(element.screenshot_as_png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).